# Truncate Markdown (sanely) in Java

Tags: java, markdown

I accept markdown as a form input on a website.  That markdown gets stored in a Java webservice, and triggers an email with the content.  For some clients, we send the Markdown in plaintext (which markdown is nice for).  However, we are currently truncating large comments to some arbitrary number of characters.

What I want is a utility in Java that can truncate Markdown to 4000 characters or less, but won't break in the middle of things like (links)[toThisWebsite].

Does this exist?

Comment: Related: [Markdown: how to show a preview (such as the first N words)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34638546/866026)

Comment: why not truncate on input instead of export? that way the users notices immediately..

Comment: We don't truncate the data (we will show it in their browser in a bunch of ways).  But we can't send many MBs of text in an email notification.