# Truncate a post.excerpt

Tags: html, markdown, ejs, hexo

I am trying to truncate a `post.excerpt`.

Actual code is `<%- post.excerpt || post.content%>`

The above shows all of the intro text of a blogpost.

Now I want to truncate that intro text to 25 characters length.

The truncate code is like in this example:

```
<%- truncate('And they found that many people were sleeping better.', {length: 25, omission: '... (continued)'}) %>`
```

Now to combine that, I came up with:

```
<%- truncate((post.excerpt), {length: 25, omission: '... (continued)'}) || post.content%>
```

But that did not work, how to make truncating work for my needs?

Full code here...

```
<section class="article typo">
    <%- post.excerpt || post.content %>
    <% if (post.excerpt) { %>
      <div class="readmore">
          <a href="<%- url_for(post.path) %>">Read More</a>
      </div>
    <% } %>
```

Comment: Truncating Markdown is much more complicated than counting characters. See [Markdown: how to show a preview (such as the first N words)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638546/866026) for a language agnostic breakdown of the steps needed to get a meaningful result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of truncating content to excerpt,
Try this

```
 `<section class="article typo">
      <%- post.content | truncatewords: 25 %>
      <div class="readmore">
      <a href="<%- url_for(post.path) %>">Read More</a>
    </div>
    <% } %>`
```

Comment: unfortunately did not work. The template engine is EJS and platform is HEXO... https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html